# Object data overide all previous data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

So basicly i have 2 components, i am using webkit simple-template to organize my code, in my project i have a issue, basicly i have something like a textarea, everytime i write something there, it should display a div with that text, so in my textarea component **i did something like this:**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                    <label>Quote:</label>
                    <textarea v-model="quote.text" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button @click="addQuote" class="btn btn-primary center">Add Quote</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { quoteBus } from '../main.js';

    export default {
        methods: {
            addQuote() {
                if (this.counter < 10) {
                    this.counter++;
                    this.quote.id = this.counter;
                    quoteBus.$emit('saveQuote', this.quote);
                }
            }
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                quote: {},
                counter: 0
            }
        },
        created(){
            quoteBus.$on('decreaseCounter', () => {
                this.counter--
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

everytime i add a quote(the text) i call the event that is in the other component that should unshift the object into the array.

**component two(with divs)**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(quote,$index) in quotes" @click="deleteQuote($index)">
            <div class="spacing">
                <h2>{{quote.text}}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { quoteBus } from '../main.js';

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                quotes: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            deleteQuote(i){
                this.quotes.splice(i,1);
                quoteBus.$emit('decreaseCounter');
            }
        },
        created() {
            quoteBus.$on('saveQuote', quote => {
                this.quotes.unshift(quote);
                console.log(quote);
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

as you guys can see, here i have the unshift that adds the object into the begin of the array, and above on the html i do a v-for to iterate over the array, everything is fine, but the divs displayed are strange, this is the behaviour:

**i place 'some Text' on the textarea, everything fine i get a div with a 'some Text**

then i place 'some Text2' on the textarea, and that 'some Text2' overides the previous object, i get all divs displayed with the text of the last input, so imagine in my 9th div i enter 'abc' all other 8 divs get the 'abc', i hope you guys understood the issue.

Ps: the console.log(quote) displays well the object that i want to unshift, it is exactly that object that i want to pass to the array, so there is no issue there.

thanks guys,

sorry for long post

**Quotes log**:

first add:

```
Array[1]0: Object__ob__: Observerid: 2text: "second"__proto__: Object1: Object__ob__: Observerid: 2text: "second"__proto__: Object__ob__: Observerlength: 2__proto__: Array
```

second add:

Array[1]0: Object__ob__: Observerid: 2text: "second"**proto**: Object1: Object__ob__: Observerid: 2text: "second"**proto**: Object__ob__: Observerlength: 2__proto__: Array

Comment: I think all those previous divs are still bound to just one model. You need to do some cloning to bind to a fresh object so the data isn't shared between all your divs. I'm still trying to parse your code, I'll try to write an answer with code changes

Comment: Can you debug or console.log out the `quotes` array?

Comment: I can't scaffold out a test. If you could make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the issue I could probably fiddle with the code for a fix. Try breaking out your looped quote as per [this sample](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Composing-with-Components) into its own component. It might be clearer what data is being bound by vue and why each element in the array isn't being shown.

Comment: sorry i wasn't here i update the question with the debug from quotes, the result is above

Comment: it just overides the array before, when i add something

Comment: Maybe try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(quotes))`? Those objects might not stringify well. Not sure how to debug vuejs better.

Comment: [{"text":"first","id":1}]
[{"text":"second","id":2},{"text":"second","id":2}]

Comment: i added 2 quotes(text) and the result is above, the first is the first array, the second array already has secod in the first index :S

Comment: im learning vue.js dunno how debug it better to :S

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to have a key that uniquely identifies each of your elements. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key
I suggest adding this

```
this.quote.id = this.counter;
this.quote.key = + new Date();//new property
```

then in your other component

```
<div class="col-md-3" v-for="(quote,$index) in quotes" @click="deleteQuote($index)" :key="quote.key">
```

Don't use your id as your key as it changes based on the position the quote is in the array.

Comment: still didn't solved, the problem remains dunno why :/